# Getting NotSupportedException exception on date selection in calendar in windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, calendar

I am doing a Windows Phone 7 application, it uses a calender control from namespace `System.Windows.Controls`. My calender control is placed inside the TabControl from the same namespace.

When I select a date am getting following "NotSupportedException" message saying :

> "This type of Collection does not support changes to its
>   SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."

What could be the reason for this type of error and could i have a solution for this?[image]

Exception details : System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
  Message=This type of Collection does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Controls.SelectedDatesCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, DateTime item)
       at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(DateTime item)
       at System.Windows.Controls.SelectedDatesCollection.AddRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarItem.AddSelection(CalendarDayButton b)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarItem.Cell_MouseLeftButtonUp(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarDayButton.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)

Comment: What exactly is throwing the exception? What does the stack trace look like? Is any of your code running when the date is selected?

Comment: Am not able to get the stack trace or disassembly of this error. This is not hitting any piece of code. In debug mode its taking me to a new tab in visualstudio "No Source Available"

Comment: I have edited to include the image of the exception.

Comment: Are you firing some kind of events after selecting a date?

Comment: In the cs file I have given nothing in the selectedDateChanged event 
 private void calTenderDate_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "Test";
        }

Comment: "Copy exception detail to the clipboard"?

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening when you change this date?
I mean is there anything handling this event? It seems you are trying to change a list (maybe the datasource from a listbox?) from an other thread than the UI thread.

Comment: I have written no code in the selectedDateChanged event. Is there any issue using silverlight calendar control inside silverlight tabcontrol?

Comment: Hmm... having a look at the stack if must be a problem of the control... Did you thought about using the calendar control from the Toolkit?